# salesforce default tab

Tags: defaults

HI I am trying to make the HOME tab as the default tab for one of my application but it is not working properly.
As when I log in to the org it is redirecting me to the set up page .
The setting image is attached [image] 
[image]

Comment: the above image is of home page. That is what you have set as Default Landing Tab. Can you ass the image of the page you want to see when your app get open.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified it in my Dev Org. As soon as I choose the sales App it opnes the Lead Tab. 
Setup -->> Create-->> Apps -->>Open the App  -->> Set the Default Landing Tab.

Comment: the same has been done as I have given you the screen shot of the app setting above. I have made the home tab as the default landing tab. But still it is not working. :( . It is landing on the set up page.

Comment: @vipul you are answer is wrong, please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

@subrat, go to your advanced user detail : and uncheck the checkbox saying :
'Make Setup My Default Landing Page'

Your name > my settings> Advanced User Details, then click Edit. Then uncheck  the checkbox- Make Setup My Default Landing Page

[image]